# Canvas does not render filters of css3

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, canvas, fabricjs

[**JSFiddle** for the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/hpA9C/).

Since canvas does not support images from cross domains, this fiddle may cause a little problem but you can always check this locally on your computer.

### HTML

```html
  <div id="html2canvas">
        <div class="htmltoken" style="left: 175px; top: 94px; -webkit-filter: sepia(1) grayscale(50%);">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/44nUYN0.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="htmltoken" style="left: 258px; top: 112px; border-color: rgb(37, 92, 189); border-width: 8px; border-top-left-radius: 100px; border-top-right-radius: 100px; border-bottom-right-radius: 100px; border-bottom-left-radius: 100px; opacity: 0.75; -webkit-filter: saturate(2.5) brightness(1) contrast(2) blur(2.5px);">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/tEpBeQV.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
            <button id="canvasMake">Make canvas</button>
```

### JavaScript (using jQuery)

```js
$('#canvasMake').click(function(){
     html2canvas(document.getElementById('html2canvas'), {
          onrendered: function(canvas) {
              document.body.appendChild(canvas);
                var dataurl = canvas.toDataURL('image/png'),
                    img = document.createElement("img");
                    img.src = dataurl;
                    document.body.appendChild(img);
         }
      });       
});
```

### Result

[image: Image of the actual result]

### Expected result (done by snipping tool)

[image: Image of the expected result]

I know that I can achieve this in some way or another with **[fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/)**.

But I am not quite sure how to get the correct output. Could someone please guide me?

Comment: That is too much js for us to go through. Please localize the problem and update the jsfiddle